# Rails 3 : How to execute action when render :action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, rendering, rescue

Rails 3 recommend Rest.
For example, I make Blog system.

```
### PostsController

# show detail
# tag have lock or unlock status
def show
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @tags = @post.tags.select("posts_tags.tag_lock")
end

### CommentsController

# Posts#show has comment form.
# when you post comment, rails execute this action
def create
 @post = @post.find(params[:id])
 begin
  @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])
 resucue
   @tags = @post.tags.select("posts_tags.tag_lock")
   render 'posts/show'
 end
end
```

if rails can execute action with render, resucue code is simple.
Maybe, a solution is to make new action. but, specifications dont have new action...
What is better? what about you??

Sorry, my english is bad..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're fine doing it the way you are (fixed some typos):

```
### PostsController

# show detail
# tag have lock or unlock status
def show
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @tags = @post.tags.select("posts_tags.tag_lock")
end

### CommentsController

# Posts#show has comment form.
# when you post comment, rails execute this action
def create
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 begin
  @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])
 rescue
   @tags = @post.tags.select("posts_tags.tag_lock")
   render 'posts/show'
 end
end
```

Comment: hi, thanks! redirect cant keeps params[:comment]... So, i wanna use render. redirect is best way??

Comment: @terut In that case I think you're fine doing it the way you are. If the posts/show action gets any more complex you might want to move the code to a method and call it from both posts/show and comments/create rather than repeating yourself.